# Lebesgue Integral of an Indicator Function using Measure Theory

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

Let $X$ be a random variable on $\Omega$ and fix $c \in \mathbb{R}$.  I recently saw the following in a calculation:
$$
\int_{\Omega} \mathbb{I}_{(c,\infty)}(X(\omega)) dP(\omega) = P(X \geq c).
$$
I thought I'd try to apply what I've learned in measure theory to make sense of this, so please let me know if the following is correct.

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space and $X$ a random variable.  For fixed $c \in \mathbb{R}$ define the function $g : \mathbb{R} \to \{0,1\}$ by $g(x) = \mathbb{I}_{(c,\infty)}(x)$.  Let $P \circ X^{-1}$ be the pushforward measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$; that is, $P \circ X^{-1}(A) = P(X \in A)$ for all $A \in \mathcal{B}$ .  Note $g$ is intergrable w.r.t. $P \circ X^{-1}$ since $(c,\infty) \in \mathcal{B}$ and $P \circ X^{-1}$ is a finite measure.  Then by the [change of variables formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure), $g \circ X: \Omega \to \{0,1\}$ is integrable w.r.t. $P$.  Hence,
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega} \mathbb{I}_{(c,\infty)}(X(\omega)) dP(\omega) & = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{I}_{(c,\infty)}(x) d(P\circ X^{-1})(x) & \qquad (1) \\
& = (P \circ X^{-1})\left((c,\infty)\right) & \qquad (2) \\
& = P(X > c), & \qquad (3)
\end{align*}
where the first line is due to the change of variables formula, the second is the definition of the integral of an indicator function and the third is the definition of the pushforward measure.

Comment: You can also call $P \circ X^{-1}$ the "distribution measure" (or just distribution) of the random variable $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do yo mean to allow equality $X(\omega)=c$, or only the strict inequality $X(\omega)>c$? The argument is the same in either case, but you have two different sets in your question (one allowing $X(\omega)=c$, the other requiring strict inequality). You don't need anything about pushforwards or  change of variables. Your composite function $\mathbf{1}_{(c,\infty)}\circ X:\Omega\to\mathbf{R}$ is in fact equal to the characteristic function $\mathbf{1}_{\{\omega\in \Omega:X(\omega)>c\}}$. (Check this!) Since $X$ is a measurable function by definition, the set $\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)>c\}=X^{-1}((c,\infty))$ is measurable, so the characteristic function of this set is measurable and its integral is equal to the measure of the set in question.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your method of proof, but the real substance of the proof relies on the fact that since $\Bbb 1_{(c,\infty)} : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is a measurable function, and $\mu(A) := P(X^{-1} (A))$ is the distribution of the random variable $X$, we have $\int \limits_{\Omega} \Bbb 1_{(c,\infty)}(X(\omega)) \,dP(\omega) = \int \limits_{\Bbb R} \Bbb 1_{(c, \infty)}(x) d\mu$.

This fact is also true if you replace $\Bbb 1_{(c,\infty)}(x) : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ with any other measurable $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$.

For a proof, see section 1.6.3 of [this book](https://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf).

Comment: I am quite interested in this proposition, but the link to the book is no longer available. Would you please name the title and author of the book?